# asm syntax highlight AND asm file display in visual studio

Tags: c, assembly, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to do some assembly coding, I call the functions from C language. The code itself runs fine, but I have two enormous problems that I cannot to tackle for quite a long time now. First of them is syntax-highlighting - I installed two different (one at the time) asm highlighting extensions to visual studio 2015 enterprise, both of them didn't work. Before I installed the 2015 version I had 2013 Ultimate and the highlighting worked fine there. I tried to delete specific files responsible from registry etc but it didn't help me achieve absolutely anything. Tried to reinstall or update the extensions is well.

Another problem I have is something that pretty much started happening for first time 3 hours ago, in a solution when I have an asm file it is fine, I can edit it freely, run it, whatever. But once I switch off visual studio and run it again in the moment when I try to open the asm file in visual studio the file is no longer in clean assembly but in OP codes written in hexadecimal and along it there is list of the memory cell in which each op is in... When I make new asm file in the solution it is fine but once I restart visual studio same thing happens. I tried to look through all the common options in the top menu bar but there seems not to be anything helpful to me in this situation....

Desperately I tried to google both of those things (first one for quite extended period of time) but it seems like some of the problems I have encountered could possibly be related to 2015 enterprise version of visual studio :(

EDIT// OK I MANAGED TO FIX THE SECOND PROBLEM - right click the .asm file and use Open With and choose another editor!!!
Help please ;(

Comment: Use one of the following extensions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Trass3r.AsmHighlighter or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Henk-JanLebbink.AsmDude

Comment: In the future, when you ask questions like this, a screenshot can be very helpful so that we can see what you are describing.

Comment: I got both of these extensions :(

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that you cannot use both. They would conflict with one another. I know for a fact that AsmDude works on VS 2015. I have it installed on my notebook right now.

Answer (score 2):

AsmDude will not work when .asm files are associated with an editor (see this issue [here](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/issues/43)). If you still experiencing problems with AsmDude, consider opening an issue on Github. I'm happy to help you there.